# How to tell Windows search not to use wildcards except if specificly asked for

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

On my Windows 10 machine, I have a folder containing lots of files (C files, Java class files, ...).

I would like to find a particular C file (extension *.c), so I have searched for *.c using Windows explorer.

However, Windows seems to be searching for *.*c*, and as a result I see all Java class files, of which I have so much that I don't find what I'm looking for in the search results.

Is there a switch which allows me to to say to Windows "Only apply the wildcards which I provide" in the Windows search feature?

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I've found my own answer: in order to force Windows 10 only to take my wildcards into account, I need to put my search parameters between double qoutes:

```
input parameters : *.c   => Windows 10 searches for *.*c* (including *.class and others)
input parameters : "*.c" => Windows 10 searches for *.c (only C source code files)
```